# setRetainInstance(true), but UI does not appear

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

I'm trying to create an Image gallery, using [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html) as a guide, with some tweaks.

So here's part of my Fragment code:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "com.example.imageencryptor.RetainedFragment";

    LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {

        initCache();

    }

    public void initCache() {
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
        cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                // The cache size will be measured in kilobytes rather than
                // number of items.
                return ImageLoader.getSizeInBytes(bitmap) / 1024;
            }
        };

    }

    public static PlaceholderFragment findOrCreateRetainFragment(
            FragmentManager fm) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = (PlaceholderFragment) fm
                .findFragmentByTag(TAG);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(fragment, TAG).commit();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

        GridView imageGrid = (GridView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader(getActivity(), cache);
        imageGrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), loader));

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

}
```

My activity's onCreate method goes like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    PlaceholderFragment.findOrCreateRetainFragment(getSupportFragmentManager());
    }
```

However, I end up with a blank UI upon starting. No grid views. Why is that?

On the other hand it would work if my onCreate is changed to this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    PlaceholderFragment pFragment = PlaceholderFragment
            .findOrCreateRetainFragment(getSupportFragmentManager());


     if (savedInstanceState == null) {
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .add(R.id.container, pFragment,PlaceholderFragment.TAG).commit();
     }

}
```

But isn't it like, adding multiple identical Fragment with the same tag, to the FragmentManager over and over again whenever the screen orientation changes?

Comment: Hi, did you test my answer below? Did you find a solution or do you need more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the UI is not displayed because you do the `FragmentTransaction` inside your interface named `findOrCreateRetainFragment`. This interface serves to pass datas from `Activity` to `Fragment` added dynamically, this will be available even if the fragment is somehow recreated by Android. You need to do your FragmentTransaction in your Activity as below:

```
// Init your fragment
PlaceholderFragment pFragment = (PlaceholderFragment) 
    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(PlaceholderFragment.TAG);

// If it is null: the fragment is not created yet - create it
if(pFragment == null) {
    // send data to interface - which will create a new one
    PlaceholderFragment pFragment = 
            new PlaceholderFragment().instanceRetainFragment(value);
    // add the new fragment
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, pFragment, PlaceholderFragment.TAG).commit();
}
// else: avoid to create the fragment again
```

And then, the interface in the Fragment might be this:

```
public static PlaceholderFragment instanceRetainFragment(int value) {
    // create a new fragment
    PlaceholderFragment mFragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
    // create a bundle to store data
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    // insert data
    args.putInt("mValue", value);
    // attach data
    mFragment.setArguments(args);
    // return new fragment in the activity
    return mFragment;
}
```

You can also create an interface without storing data and just call the first and last lines. However, it might be usefull to store and receive some informations from your Activity (for example: a `Boolean` to filter your `GridView`, an `Integer` to display only one category, etc).
So, the main issue is to call the `FragmentManager` in Fragment and not Activity. It might be the cause of "not displaying UI". Let me know if this works.